# Why would the NTFS ACL utility `icacls` alter the system partition behind the scene?

Tags: windows-7, permissions, ntfs, acl, icacls

I attached an hdd to my win7 machine and assigned the drive letter `I:` to the only partition on the hdd. The hdd was originally from another computer, and to avoid all those "you don't currently have permission..." dialogs, I decided to use `icacls` to clear all ACLs.

I ran `icacls I:\ /reset /t /c /l`. After a while, Chrome stopped working. Safari crashed. I traced the problem and find that the ACLs of my home folder (in `C:\Users`) are all messed up. Chrome and Safari couldn't write to their cache folder. I fixed the ACLs of my home folder and everything *seems* to be OK now.

**Why would `icacls` mess with my home folder when I specifically told it to work on the `I:` drive?** I have even put in the `/L` switch so that it won't resolve symbolic links. Did I misunderstood the switch?

For your reference, below is the relevant parts of the help screen.

```
ICACLS name /reset [/T] [/C] [/L] [/Q]
    replaces ACLs with default inherited ACLs for all matching files.

    /T indicates that this operation is performed on all matching
        files/directories below the directories specified in the name.

    /C indicates that this operation will continue on all file errors.
        Error messages will still be displayed.

    /L indicates that this operation is performed on a symbolic link
       itself versus its target.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK I found the answer...

The hidden `Documents and Settings` in `I:\` is a junction pointing to `C:\Users`. The target of the junction is an absolute path (as opposed to a relative path). Since `/L` takes care of symbolic links only, `icacls` resolved `I:\Documents and Settings` into `C:\Users` and reset all the ACLs there.

**Therefore, never use `icacls` unless you have examined all the junctions in the folder you want `icacls` to work on!** This makes `icacls` practically useless as a recursive ACLs modification tool... If the folder contains a junction pointing to `C:\` deep inside the folder structure, you could have killed your Windows without even knowing why!

Comment: 11 years later: Is there any solution for this? Is there any tool like icacls that does not follow hardlinks/junction points?