# fixing permissions on Win7

Tags: windows-7, permissions

I had a normally working Win7 computer a couple hours ago...
I had removed a hard drive from a broken laptop and put it into an enclosure. Then I used ICACLS to reset the permissions on it so the files could be accessed. Anyway, I don't know what happened, but I somehow changed something on my computer, not just the external drive.
I couldn't open most programs without running them as administrator (including chrome). I ran icacls "%appdata%*.*" /grant "%username%":(F) /T and now I can run Chrome but it won't sync.

I tried doing a system restore from several points from safe mode but they all fail.

I'm thinking about doing a icacls "c:*.*" /grant "%username%":(f) /T /C
will that help or just make it worse?

Comment: Sounds like you got hit with the same thing that happened here: https://superuser.com/questions/216914/why-would-the-ntfs-acl-utility-icacls-alter-the-system-partition-behind-the-sc?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike the similar listed post, my problem seemed to have no correlation to junctions.

Here is what fixed me:

first I ran this:

```
icacls "c:*.*" /grant "%username%":(f) /T /C
```

That fixed almost everything. I was still getting odd errors on some programs which still would only run if I right-clicked and ran as administrator. Finally I got an intuative error from one program that said it couldn't create a temp file in *C:\Users\userName\appdata\local\temp.*

So, I right clicked on

```
C:\Users\userName\appdata\local\temp
```

and chose properties.
Then I clicked the security tab, and my user had no permissions.
I have myself full permissions and now everything works.